# What's wrong with this implementation of a heap?

Tags: python, heap

my insert method is not correct and I don't know why. 
my min method errors with not "builtin_function or object not subscriptable"

I think that my conceptual understanding of heaps is OK. But its fracking frustrating when actually writing it down :(

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def find_children(self, index):
        """ return both the left and right children """
        return index * 2 + 1, index * 2 + 2

    def insert(self, value):
        """ append node value to the array, then bubble up
        to its rightful place
        """
        self.array.append(value)
        index = self.array.index(value)

        while index > 0 or self.array[index] < self.array[index // 2 - 1]:
            if self.array[index] < self.array[index // 2 - 1]:
                temp = self.array[index]
                self.array[index] = self.array[index // 2 - 1]
                self.array[index // 2 - 1] = temp
            index = index // 2 - 1

    def min(self):
        """ remove the min at the root, then bubble down to
        maintain heap property
        """
        minimum = self.array[0]
        self.array[0] = self.array[-1]
        self.array.pop()

        index = self.array.index[minimum]

        while index <= len(self.array):
            leftChildIndex, rightChildIndex = self.find_children(index)
            minChild = min( self.array[leftChildIndex], self.array[rightChildIndex] )
            if self.array[index] > minChild:
                temp = self.array[index]
                self.array[index] = minChild
                minChild = temp
            index = minChild

        return minimum

    def p(self):
        return self.array
```

Comment: You're using the wrong sort of brackets on `self.array.index[minimum]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it .. and that requires a vote down huh

Comment: Just to clarify the down votes: The error should have precisely stated at which line the issue is. Omitting this information and just dumping your code for others to work through is not exactly polite.

Comment: Dealer's choice of: not a [mcve], no proper traceback, trivial typo

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You didn't understand my question then. My main problem is not the syntax, it's the algorithm itself. I'm not sure the algorithm itself is correct. I don't care for the syntax error. Is the algorithm correct? that's my question

Comment: Then consider yourself down voted for asking a too broad question with broken code as well. Just dumping broken code, expecting others to fix it, understand what you've done, understand what you've been trying to do, and explain all three of these things when you couldn't be bothered to ask a clear question is... not exactly polite.

Comment: [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), or at least civil, or leave. *"Is the algorithm correct?"* - you can't possibly have tried to determine that for yourself while it's not actually working code. Have you considered *testing it?*

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.array.index(value)` in `insert` is dangerous. What happens if you do an insert of a value that already exists in the heap? You should use `len(self.array)` instead (you're appending to the array, so it'll be the last element).

Similarly, in `min`, you do effectively the same. You don't need to search for that index, you already know it.

You probably actually want to maintain your own "length" and "capacity" attributes, since growing and shrinking the backing array will stomp all over your expected log(n).